# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package when trying to import sibling inside package

Tags: python

I am trying to build a python package from one of my projects. I have a directory structure like this:

```
mypackage
    setup.py
    src
        __init__.py
        mypackage.py
        Node.py
        (... and a lot of other files and subdirectories)
```

In mypackage.py, I import the `Node` class like this:

```
from .Node import Node
```

along with a few other classes, to make them directly accessible when importing `mypackage` later. However, after successfully building the package (just using `pip install "mypackage/"` from the mypackage folder's parent dir rn), when trying to import the package in python, I get the following error

```
    from .Node import Node
    ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

From what I know, mypackage.py should absolutely be part of the package, so I don't really understand why it can't import siblings like this. In the `setup.py` file, I specify

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    <...>
    py_modules=['mymodule'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)
```

What am I missing here? I really don't know much about the import and module system in Python.

Comment: surely if you've installed the package and you want to access the Node object in the  Node module you should use `from mypackage.Node import Node` or have I misunderstood the question? You can't use relative imports to access parts of an installed package

Comment: How do you run mypackage.py? Is it a script or a module? Scripts are not part of packages and can't do relative imports in the package.

Comment: @GTBebbo the `Node` *class* is part of a collection of classes that I want to access after `import mypackage as mp` using `mp.Node` (directly, without having to import it *from* the actual Node module). I thought this would be the natural way to accomplish that. I'm not sure what you mean by "I can't use relative import to access parts of an installed package"?

Comment: @tdelaney I don't run `mypackage.py` at all. I thought it's just the file whose content actually gets directly accessible (see last comment) when importing the package. Am I wrong?

Comment: if your package is called `mypackage` then to access the `mypackage.py` file you would have to use `mypackage.mypackage`, by using `mypackage.Node` you're not using the `mypackage.py` file you're just telling python which package the `Node.py` file is in

Comment: ah, I see. But using `import mypackage.mypackage` still leads to the same error...

Answer (score 0):

To do your import you need to just write

`import Node`

This is because when you write

```
from .Node import Node
```

It thinks that your looking for a directory called Node inside the current directory and then import the Node file from there.